# Request/multiple-responses in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I've a service which should initially immediately return a result, then after a query time of around 2 minutes there is an additional response ready.

- How to implement single-request/multiple-responses with WCF?
- Best option would be to retrieve the initial result sync and the second result async, however, both async is also okay.

My only idea so far is to use a callback (duplex channel), however, with the new async features there is maybe a better way to implement such a service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEnumerable interface with streamed service. You can check following link.

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/streaming-large-content-with-wcf-and-deferred-execution